# Django detail view test model gives AssertionError: 404 != 200 in django test, but works fine in the browser

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-3.0

I am new to Django and test-driven approach, I am trying below shown test.py file but it gives Assertion Error. But code runs fine on web browser chrome. My backend is PostgreSQL. Whats is the problem with my code.

**Test.Py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Post
from django.test import Client


class BlogTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='testuser',
            email='test@email.com',
            password='secret'
        )


        self.post = Post.objects.create(
            title='A good title',
            body='Nice body content',
            author=self.user,
        )


     def test_post_detail_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/post/1/')
        no_response = self.client.get('/post/100000/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(no_response.status_code, 404)
        self.assertContains(response, 'A good title')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'post_detail.html')
```

I am receiving this error on shell :

**AssertionError:**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.F..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_post_detail_view (blog.tests.BlogTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\tests.py", line 50, in test_post_detail_view
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.894s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Below shown is my views.py file :

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView


from .models import Post


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'


class BlogDetailView(DetailView): 
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

And this si the urls.py file:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import BlogListView, BlogDetailView


urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Comment: The id is not per se 1, what if you use `response = self.client.get(f'/post/{self.post.pk}/')`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much... An error has gone with the blink of an eye. Bingo!